# Could the multiplication of matrix X (with dimensions [d+1 x N]) and its transpose simplify to a matrix with [d+1 x d+1] dimensions?

Tags: matrices, products

In a machine learning course I'm taking, one of the lectures deals with matrix multiplication.

[image: In particular, the following was presented:]
[image: Snapshot of part of slide]

Could anyone explain why the dot product of these two matrices would "shrink" to [d+1 x d+1] dimensions instead of being [N x N] dimensions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform matrix multiplication, order matters. Here, when you multiply these two matrices, the final matrix will have rows corresponding to the first matrix (so in your case, $d + 1$) and columns corresponding to the second matrix $(d + 1)$. Now, if it were instead $(\mathbf{X}^T)(\mathbf{X})$, then the opposite would be true: since $\mathbf{X}^T$ has $N$ rows and $\mathbf{X}$ has $N$ columns, the matrix multiplication would lead to a matrix with $N \times N$ dimensions.